# Include figure in the part environment

Tags: floats

I am currently writing a script for Algebra and I use the \part{...} command. I wanted to put a rubics cube .pdf figure on the same page where the title of the first part is stated but it does not work.

I tried it like this:

`\part{Group Theory} \begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`

I use `\documentclass[12pt]{report}`.

Comment: you should provide an example, but such an image is not a float, so you shouldn't use `\begin{figure}` just use `\includegraphics` also you want to add it to the definition of `\@part` as part uses  `\newpage` after the title

Comment: simplest is `\part[Group Theory]{Group Theory\\[1cm]\includegraphics{cube}} `

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\part[Group Theory]
{Group Theory\\[1cm]\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}} 

\chapter{Something}
xxx

\end{document}
```